# CANalyzer (Measure Message) via C#

Tags: c#, com, canalyzer

I have a list of different CAN messages that I need to look at. I want to choose from this list a message and measure this message in the CANalyzer (via C #)? How can I do that?

Comment: Please share what you had tried!!!

Comment: The problem is, that I have no idea how it works. The only thing that I've tried is to get a signal value.
canApp = (CANalyzer.Signal)canBus.GetSignal(1, "EngineData", 
"EngineSpeed");
But that's not really that what I really mean, and I didn't find anything in internet about measuring a message via C#.